SetWindowLongPtr Fails but GetLastError and errno are both 0
I am a novice programmer fiddling with the Windows API and attempting to follow the DirectWrite Documentation (probably shooting myself in the foot with that decision). I've entered a rabbit hole of debugging and have become stumped by this SetWindowLongPtr() function. Here is a snippet of what I'm working with:
LRESULT CALLBACK SimpleText::WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (message == WM_NCCREATE) // the sample used WM_CREATE, which doesn't even get sent by CreateWindow(). Don't know why.
    {
        LPCREATESTRUCT pcs = (LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam; // pcs gets set successfully
        SimpleText* pSimpleText_ = (SimpleText*)pcs->lpCreateParams; // the object is initialized correctly here.

        BOOL valid = IsWindowHandleValid(hwnd); //this is indeed a valid handle.
        
        SetLastError(0); //This line is supposed to guarantee GetLastError() returns properly.
        BOOL setSuccess = ::SetWindowLongPtr( // this function returns 0
            hwnd,
            GWLP_USERDATA,
            PtrToUlong(pSimpleText_)
        );

        if (!setSuccess) {
            DWORD dwError = GetLastError(); // GetLastError() is 0. errno also 0 when tested.
        }
        return 1;
    }
    //After WM_NCCREATE is called, CreateWindow() sends NCCALCSIZE which is unhandled by the example, then it calls WM_SIZE. 
    SimpleText* pSimpleText = reinterpret_cast<SimpleText*>(
        ::GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA)); // Undefined data here.

    if (pSimpleText) //passes nullcheck
    {
        switch (message)
        {
        case WM_SIZE:
        {
            UINT width = LOWORD(lParam);
            UINT height = HIWORD(lParam);
            if(pSimpleText->pRT_ != nullptr) // read access violation, uninitialized object.
                pSimpleText->OnResize(width, height);
        }
        //other cases...
        }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(
        hwnd,
        message,
        wParam,
        lParam
    );
}

Windows Documentation makes a note about 32 and 64-bit, which might be a problem. It also says the following:

The SetWindowLongPtr function fails if the process that owns the window specified by the hWnd parameter is at a higher process privilege in the UIPI hierarchy than the process the calling thread resides in.

This is above my understanding, but may also be related.
Pastebin Link to SimpleText.cpp if you need more context that I may have missed in this post.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/rules-for-using-pointers Don't use PtrToUlong unless your app is 32-bit or you never plan to use that value as a pointer again.

What's pSimpleText_ before updating it? If it's 0 or NULL, then it's fine. The function doesn't actually return a success "flag", but rather the old value or 0. A value of 0 is not a guranteed failure. From the docs: "If the previous value is zero and the function succeeds, the return value is zero, but the function does not clear the last error information. To determine success or failure, clear the last error information by calling SetLastError with 0, then call SetWindowLongPtr. Function failure will be indicated by a return value of zero and a GetLastError result that is nonzero."

Also from the docs. "If the previous value is zero and the function succeeds, the return value is zero, but the function does not clear the last error information. To determine success or failure, clear the last error information by calling SetLastError with 0, then call SetWindowLongPtr. Function failure will be indicated by a return value of zero and a GetLastError result that is nonzero." The default value is 0 so the function is probably working fine.

Beat you to it ;)

@TheNomad Yeah, but mine is fancy.

using  a C-style cast  (LONG_PTR)pSimpleText_ instead of PtrToUlong() solved it. static_cast is telling me that its an invalid type. Any advice for learning the WinAPI properly so I can minimize frustrations like these?

edit: use reinterpret_cast<ULONG_PTR>(pSimpleText_);

I'd say reading the (confusing) MS documentation extensively, patience and doing it over time to gain experience. Same as other frameworks or APIs. There isn't a magic formula. The main difference is that MS "invented" a lot of "types" that are actually not "real types" which might seem confusing, as well as the switch between A and W functions which you need to pay attention to (there is no such function called SetWindowLongPtr(), there are 2: SetWindowLongPtrA() and SetWindowLongPtrW(); SetWindowLongPtr is a PP macro).

ULONG_PTR and LONG_PTR are not the same thing. Be vary careful on how you swap types around. Also read this, this, this and this as a refresher. If a cast fails, there's a reason, so don't force it even if "it seems to work".

The function simply did not fail.  The return value gives you the previous value, 0 is rather common.  And expected for GWLP_USERDATA the first time you call it.  Do note that the return type is not BOOL, probably how this code went south.
